# Google cloud fully global image

Tags: google-compute-engine

I want to create an image which is reachable in every project for everbody.
How can I make it?
Currently I have a snapshot. I made a persistent disk with this image so my idea is to create a google storage blob and copy it across the projects and create an image in every project.
Can I somehow copy a disk into the storage account.
Or anybody has better idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to export an image to Google Cloud Storage following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#exporting_an_image_to_google_cloud_storage) that you can find in the documentation.

After that you should be able to run the following command:

```
gcloud compute images create IMAGE_NAME --project PROJECT --source-uri gs://BUCKET_NAME/IMAGE_NAME.image.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

as per Adrian's answer:

Sadly Google don't make your life easy here... frankly the lack of easy Image migration project-to-project is a bit of a thumbs down at the moment for GCE.